# PHP, query strings and ampersands - how to ensure it works correctly?

Tags: php, query-string

I have a PHP site, on an Apache 2.2 server, with MySQL.

It has its own virtual host at:

www.mybusinesssite1.localhost

I've got some basic content extracted from MySQL in the PHP; no issues so far with that.

What I am trying to do is to get URLs like this with query strings:

http://www.chevrolet.com.pk/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=48

Notice how that has option=com_content, task, view etc. - and that's what I'm trying to emulate on my development/sandbox site.

I've forgotten how to do query strings, because I've been busy learning .htaccess and PHP template coding, what would I need to do to achieve this effect?

I've had a look online but am not quite sure how to do this, or the best way to progress on this without breaking my site; since my site is going to be moved from localhost to a live server, I don't want it to be broken on launch.

Comment: I don't understand what your question is exactly?

Comment: Are you asking how to generate a GET request with parameters?

Comment: Simply, Google "URL Rewriting in PHP"

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel mentioned, all the URL query strings are in the $_GET super global array. Just issue this to see the structure:

```
print_r($_GET);
```

If you have url text strings that you want to parse as if they were real URLs, use parse_str();